# Iframe resize varies with browsers

Tags: php, iframe

Hi I am trying to add a photo-gallery to our music circle website. I have a php page which opens pages from subdirectory 'media' in an iframe. On StackOverflow question 9162933 I found a way to dynamically resize the iframe (thanks BlueFish!) and that works well except that the iframe is a few pixels too small.

The odd thing is that the "few pixels" varies from browser to browser. I added a parameter "padding" to the PHP for testing purposes, so that for example a call to http://maladrerie.heliohost.org/mkh/mediapag.php?item=2013_01_17_1&padding=15 will call http://maladrerie.heliohost.org/mkh/media/2013_01_17_1.html with a padding of 15px. The padding defaults to 35px and is displayed in the left sidebar.

The relevant PHP code is:

```
<?php if ( isset ($_GET["item"]) ) {
    $item = "media/" . $_GET["item"] . ".html" ;
} else {
    $item="media/lijst.html" ;
}
   if ( isset ($_GET["padding"]) ) {
        $padding = $_GET["padding"] ;
} else {
        $padding = 35 ;
}
?>
```

The iframe calling line is:

```
<iframe class="mediaframe" onload="resizeIframe(this)" frameborder="no" src="<?php print($item) ; ?>" > </iframe>
```

and the javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    iframe.height = (iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + <?php print($padding) ; ?>) + "px";
  }
</script>
```

Safari and Chrome need no padding (padding=0); Firefox, Opera, IE8 and IE10 need padding of 16; IE7 needs padding of 30 (I do not have IE9 on my test machines).

Any suggestions how I should handle this? The site is in Dutch but should be self-explanatory if you choose "Foto's en Geluid" in the menu.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

--- Derek

Comment: Update: I just noticed I had the wrong CSS for page http://maladrerie.heliohost.org/mkh/media/lijst.html. Please update that page before viewing the rest of the site. Sorry!

Comment: Update again: I have changed the default to 45px (I am experimenting with Yahoo Media Player and that needs more padding). Still hoping one of you whizzkids can help me...